# Angular JS Date format filter inside Ng-Repeat not formatting

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Actual Date coming from JSON

[image]

Need to format it as below .

```
Effective Date : 2010-08-31 (trim the time stamp)
End Date : 2010-08-31 (trim the time stamp)
```

Am using the below code for Formatting the date inside Ng-Repeat.

```
    <li ng-repeat="product in data | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize"
           ng-click="getAttributes(product)">   
       {{product.prod_start_date| date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
       {{product.prod_end_date| date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
    </li>
```

But it doesnt work still displays the same.

Should the Date be passed as new Date as shown in the below jsfiddle Example
    http://jsfiddle.net/southerd/xG2t8/

Note sure how to do that inside ng-repeat.?? Kindly help me on this. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I created my own filter to address this.
The date filter cant take a string, needs a date object.

```
.filter('cmdate', [
    '$filter', function($filter) {
        return function(input, format) {
            return $filter('date')(new Date(input), format);
        };
    }
]);
```

then you can do:

```
{{product.prod_start_date| cmdate:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
```

Comment: Was trying to do a similar function but nested inside $scope and glad I found this which is helpful (and can be easily reused across different areas). Thanks. Upvoted!

Comment: Thanks, this really helps me

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has solved my problem with multiple-date-picker

Answer (score 5):

I use moment.js for my UI date time handling (there even a nice `angular-moment` bower package as well)

- http://momentjs.com
- https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

usage:

```
<span>{{product.prod_start_date | amDateFormat:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span>
```

It has a bunch of other options as well with relative dates etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the controller that you showed in the fiddle and here is your [updated filter](http://jsfiddle.net/xG2t8/761/)

Here I made use of the [$filter('date')](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) which is a feature of Angular itself in order to format the date in the desired format.

Here is the controller:

```
function Scoper($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.s = "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z";
    var dateObj = new Date($scope.s);
    $scope.dateToShow = $filter('date')(dateObj,'yyyy-MM-dd');
    console.log($scope.dateToShow);
}
```